# Encoding page cookie within fetchxml inside a SOAP call to MS CRM 2013 on-demand

Tags: javascript, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working with a software program that can only talk to Dynamics using simple javascript and SOAP. Responses can only be processed in E4X. I've done really well so far but am now stumped. When sendind a SOAP to CRM that contains FetchXML I need to encode the FetchXML inside the rest of the SOAP Body which is fine. But if I want to move to the next page beccause of the 5000 row limit I have to use a page cookie which also needs to be encoded. I just can't get the syntax correct. Has anyone had this sort of problem? Can anyone show me what a vaild SOAP call looks like with the page cookie correctly encoded inside the FetchMXL part of the entire SOAP call?

Comment: Here is the code to bring back first page <CR>

Comment: sFetchXML='<![CDATA[<fetch version="1.0" page="1" page-cookie="" paginoutput-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false"> '+
'<entity name="account"> '+
'<attribute name="accountnumber"/> '+
'<attribute name="accountid"/> '+
'<filter type="and"> '+
'</filter> '+
'</entity> '+
'</fetch>]]>'

Comment: But whatever I try to put in the page-cookie fails. The cookie looks like <cookie page="1"><accountid last="{6ECD508E-8B1C-E211-AA6D-D48564519CA4}" first="{39D3B330-D203-E111-B2A9-18A905730937}" /></cookie>.  So if I try to replace " with &quot; it fails and if I try to replace all xml with &gt;, &lt; it errors with:  Paging cookie is required when trying to retrieve a set of records on any high pages.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the "page" within your FetchXML?

```
<fetch version='1.0' mapping='logical' count='5' page='2'>
    <entity name='way_target'>
        <all-attributes />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

To start, you may not even need to specify the paging cookie.  Try requesting page 2 without the paging cookie at all.  In the example above, paging works fine and adding the paging cookie doesn't alter my return (even when I want it to).

Anyhow, your paging cookie should be returned upon your first page request.  Page 1 should not send a pagingCookie value but if there are more than 5,000 records a pagingCookie will be returned.  You are supposed to send this paging cookie back in the same format you receive it in.

Here's an example response:

```
&lt;cookie page="1"&gt;&lt;way_target last="{8A3461CA-91AC-E011-8E1B-005056B37E8A}" first="{6C034728-00F2-E111-A489-0050569D0006}" /&gt;&lt;/cookie&gt;
```

Here it is in my Fetch call:

```
<fetch version='1.0' mapping='logical' count='5' page='2' PagingCookie='&lt;cookie page="1"&gt;&lt;way_target last="{6C034728-00F2-E111-A489-0050569D0006}" first="{6C034728-00F2-E111-A489-0050569D0006}" /&gt;&lt;/cookie&gt;'>
    <entity name='way_target'>
        <all-attributes />
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Yes I am and have added an example